# Можно ли вытворять такое в SQL-запросе?

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы. в первой хранится список чего-либо, и есть специальный столбец для категорий, которые записываются туда в виде цифр. Во второй таблице "расшифровки" категорий. Т.е. каждой цифре соответствует слово.
С помощью JOIN'a можно сделать так, чтобы на страницу выдавалась одна таблица, в которой вместо цифры в столбце категории стояло слово, соответствующее цифре.
Но как сделать то же самое, если в первой таблице в столбце категорий не одна цифра?
Пример:
Таблица 1

```
+---------+----+  
|bla-bla  |   3|  
+---------+----+  
|bla-bla  | 1 2|  
+---------+----+
```

Таблица 2

```
+--+---------+  
| 1|type-1   |  
+--+---------+  
| 2|type-2   |  
+--+---------+ 
| 3|type-3   |  
+--+---------+
```

В результате должно получиться такое:

```
+---------+-------------+  
|bla-bla  |type-3       |  
+---------+-------------+  
|bla-bla  |type-1 type-2|  
+---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

эта задача решается так:
таблицы {поля} :

```
category {id, name}
product {id, name}
product_categories {product_id, category_id}
```

запрос:

```
select p.name, c.name
from
category c,
product p,
product_categories pc
where p.id = pc.product_id
and c.id = pc.category_id
order by p.name /* можно по c.id - как вам удобнее */
```

p.s. имеет смысл почитать про реляционные БД и нормальные формы.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, таких возможностей SQL не предоставляет, чтобы возвращать мультивариантные поля. Попробуй пересмотреть таблицы, нормализовать их так, чтобы отдельно были поля с кодами.

Comment: Если так, то очень печально...

Answer (score 0):

Знаю тучу мест где народ так и работает - есть некое поле куда набито цифирек (или как вариант символов) - в зависимости от положения цифр (ну как битовое поле) что-то имеется ввиду. Например если символ в 17-й позиции равен "1" запись считается помеченной на удаление :)

Причем используют то это компании такие **добрые**, не ЧП "Пупкин", а из тех рекламой которых завешены все наши улицы и по ТВ они долбятся раз по 100 на дню.

Я сначала былфшоке пробовал возмущаться, учить людей доброму-вечному говорил о теореме Бойса-Кодда и проч. ерунде - потом понял, что это жизнь. И это такзять ***industry-standard*** или как иногда говорят ***vendor-specific legacy system***.

Comment: Будем ждать расширений SQL для работы с такими "векторами". Как не пытались свести жизнь к реляционной модели, а природа берет свое.

Comment: уже есть, напр. nested tables у оракла

Comment: Да в TecDoc  такое тоже делается - ищут определенную позицию в поле и сравнивают ее со значением

Comment: Неа, уэб-девелоперы скоро уйдут с SQL потому что им это сложно. Да и собственно они никогда и не были серьезной аудиторией.

Comment: Ну уэб девелопер без знания SQL - это наверное PHP-шники? На Java большиство работают через JPA подобные фреймворки, а там особо не забалуешь